# RegEx-Help. Trying to select (1) lines and (2) filter ips from these lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I will try to illustrate my issue:

I have some terminal-output that looks like this:

[image: my terminal output]

**First:**
From this list i want to filter (for example) all processes from Safari. So I will get the lines that i marked blue on the picture.

**Second:**
From the new List (the filtered Safari-lines) i want to get the ip after the "**->**" signs until "**:http**"

Therefore i use this regex:

```
var regexp = /->(.*):/g;
var ip = regexp.exec(*TheBigListWithAllConnections*)[1];
console.log(ip);
```

But this regex only gives me the first found ip. But i want alle of the ips.

It would be nice to have some hints how to reach this goal!

Answer (score 2):

You are only looking at the first line in the results of `regexp.exec();`

You have a `[1]` at the end, which in this function gives you just the 1st match.

try a loop, starting at 1 which stores the ip for each line by replacing `[1]` with `[i]`

Edit: Some [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the IP addresses in an array use this loop:

```
var regexp = /->([^:]+)/g,
    matches = [],
    input = TheBigListWithAllConnections;

while (match = regexp.exec( input ))
   matches.push( match[1] );

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: sounds and works great. but first i want to filter all the lines which belong to one application (for example like above: safari). so first i want to select all the lines according to "Safari" and than i want to scan the ip-adresses with the code you wrote.
do i need another regex to select these lines? how do they have to look like?